KV cache quantization in LLMs
I am trying to increase the throughput in my distributed system so that the number of programs generated by the LLMs is maximum. Now that KV quantization is available I am using it (LMDeploy framework), 4-bit specifically. However, throughput is not increased. I am using Qwen2.5-7B Instruct model. I have seen a table in LMDeploy documentation that compares throughput vs. X-bit quantization and not in all LLMs is increased. Does anyone know why this can happen? The table is attached in this post.
I tried 4-bit quantization in Qwen2.5-7B Instruct
